# useEffect cleanup on unmount with dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need a way to run a React useEffect cleanup function on component unmount only, but using the latest state from the component.

Consider the following example:

```js
const [foo, setFoo] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    if(foo) 
      console.log("T") 
    else
      console.log("F")
  }
}, [])

...later:

setFoo(false)
```

In this example, "T" will be printed on unmount even though the current value of `foo` is `false`.

Your first thought might be to add `foo` to the dependency array of the effect, but this causes the effect to clean up twice: once when the state changes to `false` (printing "T"), and once when the component unmounts (printing "F").

I would like it only to print "F", once the component unmounts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution to this problem is to use `useRef` as follows:

```js
const [foo, setFoo] = useState(true)

// Store value of foo and keep it up-to-date.
const fooRef = useRef(foo)
useEffect(() => fooRef.current = foo, [foo]);

// Use ref value.
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    if(fooRef.current) 
      console.log("T") 
    else
      console.log("F")
  }
}, [])

...

setFoo(false)
```